# How to row-align 3 buttons with a form each?

Tags: html, css, forms, button

I am trying to align 3 buttons in a row but so far nothing has worked. I have emptied my CSS.
What is the best way to achieve a line row with the buttons?

Maybe there is a way to do this code with only 1 form.

HTML

```
 <form action="link1" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 1</button></form>
 <form action="link2" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 2</button></form>
 <form action="link3" method="post"> <button type="submit">Button 3</button></form>
```

[Screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Iyz.png)

Thank you very much!

UPDATE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">  
</head>
<body>

<div class='container'>
  <form action="#" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 1</button></form>
  <form action="#" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 2</button></form>
  <form action="#" method="post"> <button type="submit">Button 3</button></form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    display:flex
}
```

[image: Still doesn't work..]

UPDATE 2: Error was fixed, it was in the path because I am using Flask I need to put the CSS inside a CSS folder. Now it is working. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Patricia Bota, please, try to set  `display:flex` for the container of these 3 forms. Let me know if it works.

Comment: @AskMen
CSS
.containter{
 display:flex;
}
HTML
<div class="containter" >
<form action="link1" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 1</button></form>
 <form action="link2" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 2</button></form>
 <form action="link3" method="post"> <button type="submit">Button 3</button></form>
</div>

Did not work :(

Comment: use .grid container

Comment: I dont know why but I cannot post answer

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: @PatriciaBota, please, check the path:     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css">  . It is 100% correct?

Comment: @AlpErenGül
Still doesn't work...

```
<div class="grid-container">
 <div class="grid-item"> <form action="#" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 1</button></form></div>
<div class="grid-item">  <form action="#" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 2</button></form></div>
<div class="grid-item">  <form action="#" method="post"> <button type="submit">Button 3</button></form></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AlpErenGül

```
.grid-container {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}
.grid-item {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: use .grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 50px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container {
display:flex
}
```

```html
<div class="container" >
  <form action="link1" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 1</button></form> <form action="link2" method="post"><button type="submit">Button 2</button></form> <form action="link3" method="post"> <button type="submit">Button 3</button>
  </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Patricia Bota, is this what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thank you. very much for your help!
But I still get the buttons in a column.. Should I have any link in the HTML head?

Comment: @PatriciaBota, please show more your code. If you put the forms inside container and set it to display:flex then you won't have issues. Probably is something wrong with your code

Comment: I edited my question with your solution and my entire code.